# xrdp ubuntu aws missing text

Tags: amazon-web-services, remote-desktop, xrdp

I can connect to my remote desktop (Ubuntu 16.04) in [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-ubuntu-1604-windows/) but I cant view the text at all. I am using [Microsoft Remote Desktop 10 in Apple's App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/microsoft-remote-desktop-10/id1295203466?mt=12).

[image]

So I cant login properly as explained [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305).

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Amazon Lightsail, and Ubuntu 18.04. I am also using the Mac App Store version of the xrdp client. It's a fresh install of both server and client xrdp and is just broken right out of the box.

Comment: Same problem with xrdp 0.9.5 when I rdp connect to a physical Ubuntu 18.04 desktop with all updates & upgrades applied.  I am using Microsoft Remote Desktop 10.3.9 on macOS 10.15.3

Answer (score 5):

This should now be fixed in xrdp v0.9.9 (https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/releases/tag/v0.9.9)

The bug was "Glyph cache v2 (fixes no font issue on iOS/macOS/Android client)"

Will probably need to build it from source - most Ubuntu packages still back on 0.6 or 0.9.5

Comment: Thanks! I confirm this works, after building xrdp v0.9.14 and xorgxrdp v0.2.14 on ubuntu 16.04 following https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/wiki/Building-on-Debian-8